# What was the last life sign of Satoshi Nakamoto?

Tags: history, satoshi-nakamoto

I heard that the name may be a pseudonym and that very little is known about the initiator of bitcoin. Also it seems that he has stopped working on the main client.

**When was his last verifiable life sign? Did he ever mention or announce his retirement?**

Comment: I'd say this is substantially different from the "who is" question.

Comment: @nealmcb While it *is* substantially different, it only matters that it's sufficiently different to not be an *exact* duplicate.  It clearly meets that threshold (although whether it is off-topic is a separate issue).

Comment: It's off topic. This site is about Bitcoin. It doens't need to become fodder for Who-is-Satoshi-Nakamoto trivia. Any biographical information you feel the need to expound on can easily be contained in the other thread. No need to perpetuate this this content of dubious value through the site.

Comment: In my opinion, a security relevant and trust demanding software like bitcoin, needs that nearly all questions about their developers should are allowed. More on meta: http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32/should-we-allow-question-about-the-developers

Comment: @Robert You claimed (probably rightly so IMO) that it was off-topic, yet you closed it as "exact duplicate."  It's a pet peeve of mine that far, far too many questions on SE are closed as **exact** duplicate when they are NOT **exact** duplicates.

Comment: Michael McGowan: It **is** off topic, but I was trying to compromise by providing a reference to the *other* Satoshi thread to provide an outlet for that content (closing as dupe provides a link to that content). But since the other thread has been closed, too, might as well make a clean break of it and close *this* one as off topic, too.

Comment: @Robert- I say this is on topic.

Comment: Why this question was closed? I really didn't understand the reason. I had the same doubt of the author of the question. It is very important to Bitcoin history and community. Seriously, this question is basic and if it is "off topic" I don't know what can be said or questioned about Bitcoin here. The Bitcoin wiki should be enough. This is definitely not off-topic and must be re-opened.

Comment: Don't look at the man behind the curtain...

Comment: No one knows for sure as he could still be involved with Bitcoin in some way. Around late 2010/2011 was the last public appearance. I think Hal and Satoshi had some convos after, but he has effectively disappeared. I'd speculate that Satoshi is Wenbo Mao, but no one knows

Answer (score 13):

[This was his last post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2228.msg29479#msg29479) on the Bitcoin Forums, December 12th, 2010. The day after [he wrote this](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=26744510) to the mailing list. As far as I know he did not (publicly) announce his retirement.

Answer (score -1):

The creator of Bitcoin Satoshi Nakamoto sent his final emails to fellow developers in which he was transparent that he had moved on to other projects, during the time of handing over a cryptographic key he had utilized to send network-wide alerts.